# How to continously stream audio over the web

Tags: php, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I'm trying to make a web app that will continually stream audio in real time and can not be delayed (other than a few seconds). Ideally I would like to stream directly from my house, but I'm not sure how that would be done, and how others could listen to the stream by going to a url? Once I have the content streaming, I have no problem creating the web app to play the content.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I realize you are trying to create it, but have you looked into Shoutcast?
http://www.shoutcast.com/download

Comment: I don't have to create it... I just need to do it somehow, either I build it or use a service. I'll check out Shoutcast. Thanks!

Comment: It needs to be PHP? or it can be a linux app that you are able to run in your pc/server ?

Comment: linux app is fine. I guess the web part of it would be in php which is why I put it in there

Comment: The web application is the audio source?  Or the player?  What audio will be streamed?  Voice?  Music?

Comment: the web application is the player (I can do that part) I just want to stream something from lets say my home computer. And it's voice that I would broadcast

Comment: You can try this nodejs application: http://dj.stage9.ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vlc 0.8.4 to capture/load the audio in the vlc.  configure the streaming.  Register to a DNS server on the net, it is free.  Open the port 8080 on your router (see portforwarding). Then on another computer outside your lan (outside your home) run VLC on this and type http://your dns server ip address:8080.

You will need to play with the video and audio setting on the vlc on the server side.  the result is great